# tried to deploy spring boot project on weblogic, unable to invoke controller from dispatcherServlet

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd">
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="controller" />
</beans>
```

i have used above code in dispatcher servlet. and trying to call controller from dispatcher servlet

Comment: Why the XML? Ditch it. Just create a war as explained in the reference guide.

Comment: spring boot project is to be deployed on weblogic server, can we deploy without xml file?

Comment: Again as mentioned follow documentation. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.0.M1/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-traditional-deployment (it explains in detail what you need to do).